# Show messages from plumber API in shiny APP

Tags: r, shiny, plumber, waiter

I have API in plumber which has `msg` endpoint which executes `slow_function`. I also have shiny APP in which I make `msg` endpoint request. Is it possible to somehow capture messages from API and display them in shiny APP?

slow function:

```
slow_function <- function() {
  
  messages <- character(0)
  for (i in 1:5){
    message(paste("Step:", i))
    Sys.sleep(2)  
  }
  
 TRUE
}
```

I could capture messages with `withCallingHandlers` if `slow_function` runs in APP but as soon as I replace with request to the API it does not work.

APP

```
library(shiny)
library(waiter)
library(httr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  waiter::useWaiter(),
  
  actionButton(
    inputId = "run_fun",
    label = "Run Function"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$run_fun, {
    
    total_process <- character(0)
    my_waiter <- waiter::Waiter$new()
    
    my_waiter$show()
    on.exit(my_waiter$hide())
    
    withCallingHandlers(
      slow_function(), #"httr::GET("http://localhost:8000/msg"),
      message = function(m){
        total_process <<- paste(total_process, m$message, sep = "<br>")
        my_waiter$update(HTML(total_process))
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

API:

```
library(plumber)

#* Run Slow Function with Messages
#* @get /msg
function(){
  slow_function()
}

## Run this to run api
# pr <- plumb("plumber.R")
# pr$run(port=8000)
```

Is there some way to display messages from running function within API in APP? This is important to me becaue my `slow_function` is within R package which has dependencies that I dont want to have on frontend and this step display would drastically improve user experience.

Comment: Once you `httr::GET(..)` from your API, according to your shiny app it will be just another HTTP endpoint, meaning there is no way for the shiny app to capture what may or may not be `message`d to the console on the plumber side. If you choose to capture the output within the plumber function and then have that passed to the shiny app, then .. you need your structure to account for that, and it cannot be done in realtime, since a plumber api always returns everything all at once.

Comment: It sounds like your plumber api is expected to take some time, so one thought is that you handle the parallelism and deconfliction within the plumber side. Have three endpoints in plumber: `/start` which returns some unique ID; `/status?id=<x>` to see if there are any updates to that id's processing;, then `/results?id=<x>` to actually retrieve the results.